# I am not able to create the table in SQL when entering multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is my SQL file and the table is not created when I try to insert more than 1 foreign keys in the sql. The error is ""Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

```
 CREATE TABLE company_domaindetails (
    domain_id int NOT NULL,
    domain_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_provider VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_accoemail VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_allopassword VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_dns VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_timeframe VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_daysremaining VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    company_id int,
    company_name varchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (domain_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company_details(company_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (company_name) REFERENCES company_details(company_id)    
);
```

From the (now deleted) comments:

```
CREATE TABLE company_details
(
   company_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   company_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
   company_address VARCHAR(200), 
   company_contactperson VARCHAR(200), 
   company_contactno VARCHAR(200), 
   company_email VARCHAR(200) 
);
```

Comment: The last one looks a bit odd. A name to an id.

Comment: Poor normalization anyway. Skip the company_name column in this table.

Comment: Why are you trying to set foreign key for two columns(company_id, company_name) in same table (company_details)

Comment: why you want to add foreign key to company_name colunm

Comment: `company_name referencing company_id` makes no sense. You can't reference a (supposedly) integer column (`company_id`) from a varchar column

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify once the foreing key creation and add both columns.
Check the below

```
CREATE TABLE company_details ( company_id int NOT NULL, company_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
 company_address VARCHAR(200), company_contactperson VARCHAR(200),
  company_contactno VARCHAR(200), company_email VARCHAR(200),
 PRIMARY KEY (company_id,company_name) )
```

As per the DDL you provided and specfyin the table name as `company_domaindetails`

```
CREATE TABLE company_domaindetails (
    domain_id int NOT NULL,
    domain_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_provider VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_accoemail VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_allopassword VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_dns VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_timeframe VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    domain_daysremaining VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    company_id int not null,
    company_name varchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (domain_id,company_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id,company_name) REFERENCES company_details(company_id,company_name)
    )
```